# How can I upload a file in a reactjs and save the path to the file in the JSON server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload, filepath, json-server

What should i do here to get the path
const [file, setFile] = useState("");

```
function handleUpload(e) {
     setFile(e.target.files[0]);
//what should i do here to get the path
}
```

```
 <Button variant="contained" component="label" >Upload File <input type="file" hidden  webkitdirectory onChange={(e)=>handleUpload(e)}/></Button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For security reasons browsers do not allow this, i.e. JavaScript in browser has no access to the File System, however using HTML5 File API, only Firefox provides a mozFullPath property, but if you try to get the value it returns an empty string:

possible of [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15201071/7037138)